# How should I escape ldap special characters?

Tags: python, active-directory, ldap, ldap-query, python-ldap

I'm using python-ldap to query Active Directory

I have this DN

```
CN=Whalen\, Sean,OU=Users,OU=Users and Groups,DC=example,DC=net
```

That works fine as a base in a query, but if I try to use it in a search filter like this

```
(&(objectClass=group)(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=Whalen\, Sean,OU=Users,OU=Users and Groups,DC=example,DC=net))
```

I get a `Bad search filter` error. From my testing, the comma in the CN seems to be the culprit, even though I escaped it with a backslash (`\`). But, comma isn't  listed in the [Microsoft documentation](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5312.active-directory-characters-to-escape.aspx#LDAP_Filters) as a character that needs escaped in filters.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you try adding a second backslash? Depending on how the search is executed the first backslash might need escaping to come through to the LDAP ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The LDAP filter specification assigns special meaning to the following characters `* ( ) \ NUL` that should be escaped with a backslash followed by the two character ASCII hexadecimal representation of the character *when used in a search filter* ([rfc2254](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2254#page-5)) :

```
*   \2A
(   \28
)   \29
\   \5C
Nul \00
```

That means any backslash used for escaping a *Distinguished Name' special character* (including commas) must be represented by `\5c` in a search filter :

```
(&(objectClass=group)(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=Whalen\5c, Sean,OU=Users,OU=Users and Groups,DC=example,DC=net))
```

Here is the list of dn special characters that must be escaped with `\`, or whith `\5C` when used in a search filter :

```
    +-------------------------------+---+
    | comma                         | , |
    +-------------------------------+---+
    | Backslash character           | \ |
    +-------------------------------+---+
    | Pound sign (hash sign)        | # |
    +-------------------------------+---+
    | Plus sign                     | + |
    +-------------------------------+---+
    | Less than symbol              | < |
    +-------------------------------+---+
    | Greater than symbol           | > |
    +-------------------------------+---+
    | Semicolon                     | ; |
    +-------------------------------+---+
    | Double quote (quotation mark) | " |
    +-------------------------------+---+
    | Equal sign                    | = |
    +-------------------------------+---+
    | Leading or trailing spaces    |   |
    +-------------------------------+---+
```

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed response. The query now seems to be running,, but, after taking the same amount of time as in PowerShell, it's returning zero results. Any ideas why?

Comment: I don't know, it would be worthwhile to ensure the query is correcly parsed by ldap. Depending on what is performing the query (what kind of program and how it parses strings), and as heiglandreas suggested, it may be needed to escape the backslash itself (to be parsed as a literal backslash), resulting in `\\5c`.

Comment: @EricLavault I have also had strange problems with zero results after escaping the search term correctly, but only when doing a recursive search.  I've added a full description as an answer.

Comment: @SeanW. Since the escaping of \ to \5C caused your `Bad search filter` error to disappear, I think there's a weird interplay between python string escaping and AD escaping.  Since \5C was then being sent to AD, you hit the defect with AD recursive searches (see answer below) when \ is escaped to \5C.  I suggest you escape \ to \\ and not \5C, so the end of the search term would be `CN=Whalen\\, Sean,OU=Users,OU=Users and Groups,DC=example,DC=net`.  My guess is that python will parse the \\ to a \ which will be sent to Active Directory, and all will be well.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced very odd behaviour when searching with `member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941` with escaped characters.

It seems that the search fails when the search term is escaped 'properly', but succeeds when the search term is not escaped!

In contrast, a plain search using `member` works whether the search term is escaped or not.

Here's a PowerShell example.

```
function Find-AdObjects([string]$Filter) {

    $DirectorySearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
    $DirectorySearcher.SearchRoot = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry
    $DirectorySearcher.SearchScope = [System.DirectoryServices.SearchScope]::Subtree
    $DirectorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add('distinguishedname') > $null
    $DirectorySearcher.PageSize = 100
    $DirectorySearcher.Filter = $Filter

    $SearchResultCollection = $DirectorySearcher.FindAll()

    foreach ($r in $SearchResultCollection) {
        $r.Properties['distinguishedname']
    }

    $SearchResultCollection.Dispose()
    $DirectorySearcher.Dispose()
}

$UserDn        = 'CN=Rees\, John,OU=Tier3,DC=big,DC=com'
$EscapedUserDn = 'CN=Rees\5C, John,OU=Tier3,DC=big,DC=com'

# Returns expected results with escaped search term
Find-AdObjects "(&(member=$EscapedUserDn))"

# Returns same results even though search term is NOT escaped correctly
Find-AdObjects "(&(member=$UserDn))"

# Returns NO results even though search term is escaped correctly
Find-AdObjects "(&(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=$EscapedUserDn))"

# Returns recursive results even though search term is NOT escaped correctly
Find-AdObjects "(&(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=$UserDn))"
```

So I do not see an acceptable workaround, since there does not seem to be a reliable way to escape a DN that could contain a variety of special characters: \*()